# Is it possible to protect json api scraping using random tokens?

Tags: json, web-services, api, angularjs, laravel

I have built a restful json api for an online store using Laravel.

I now wish to create an AngularJS app to run the front-end web application. Product prices for my store need to update every second, so Angular needs to get the product json from the server once per second to update the html.

I wish to somehow protect this json data from being stolen by scrapers / bots repetitively hitting my api to steal my product and pricing data.

My thoughts:

Each json api response contains a random use-once token (i am aware about doing stuff to stop collisions).

This random token is injected via AngularJS into a hidden field within the html page.
Angularjs reads the hidden token prior to re-requesting the api and uses this in the header of the next get request.

A json response is only provided with the correct token in the header. Once the token is used, it expires, and any attempt to re-use the expired token, results in that IP address being locked out for a period of time or flagged to administrator to investigate.

Is there a better way of doing the above? Are there any kind of actual available solutions to my problem? Considering that I am paying for the product pricing feed in the first place, I really don't want some schmuck getting it from me for free just because I exposed an api!

Comment: You also need to rate-limit the token distribution.

Comment: Aaah, so could i expire tokens after say 10 minutes. That way a new token will be valid for a period of 10m, and as such, my db server isn't going mental creating and managing tokens?

Comment: That doesn't prevent an attacker from grabbing a new token every after each call.

Comment: Have you considered making the data only available to logged in users? You can then track and rate limit user tokens instead of having one, centralized app token that can be compromised?

Comment: @r3mus - The app is an online store. Why would a user log-in to check the price of a product?

Comment: If they need to update every second, then maybe it's worth it? Or load the cached prices for not logged in users and only update /s for logged in users?

Comment: @r3emus - ok, interesting suggestion. One other thought... What if the password / key provided by the server was an encrypted unix timestamp. And the api would only serve the json api if the get request had a timestamp input within `5s` of the last get request?

Comment: Security by obscurity. Once someone decoded the timestamp, they'd know. Not impossibly, but probably a huge admin overhead.

Comment: Tempted to suggest we get this migrated to programmers.SE, hard to say tho.

Comment: @remus - I know that if somebody really wants your data, they will find a way to get it... But my thoughts based on comments so far is that there is no real/official way of protecting json data from theft. Despite this, if I can do something simple which would make it a little more difficult for an average programmer to simply use curl on my api to steal my entrie product feed, then yes - it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say an easier solution is to add signing to your api and store a secret key in your Angular app. This is a pretty good resource that has helped me in the past:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

Also here is a (potentially) relevant SO answer: [REST api authenication with laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461029/rest-api-authenication-with-laravel)